# Is 'avocardio' a pun?

Tags: puns

My coworker has a shirt where it's a picture of an avocado riding a bicycle. The joke? Avocardio!

My coworker says the joke is a pun. It's definitely a play on words, but I always thought a pun had to play on a word with two meanings. A classic example: what do you call a mix between an elephant and a rhino? Eleph-ino (hell-if-I-know).

Like elephino, avacardio is an absurd sounding mashup between the two words. But unlike elephino, avacardio doesn't have a meaning on its own. Therefore, I'm not sure if it counts as a pun.

Am I getting "pun" mixed up with "double entendre"? Or is the shirt, in fact, not a pun?

Comment: It's certainly a play on words (you need to supply a definition of 'pun'). How good a pun it is is a different masher.

Comment: Pretty puny, I'd say.

Comment: According to google: "a joke exploiting the different possible meanings of a word or the fact that there are words which sound alike but have different meanings."

Comment: What dictionaries did you reference for the meaning of "pun"?

Comment: I just googled: "define pun"

Comment: @HotLicks Is this a puny punny joke?  Or just a puny pun?

Comment: Aye, started a pun, which started the whole world crying.

Comment: Butt I didn't see that the yoke was on me.

Comment: So I started to fry, which started the whole wheat laughing.

Comment: Oh, if I'd only seen that the yoke was on me.

Comment: I looked at the fries, running my hands over their eyes.

Comment: And I fell out of bed, scrambling my head with the stuff I just said.

Comment: Till I finally fried, which started the whole world eating.

Comment: Oh, if I'd only seen that the yoke was on me.

Answer (score 4):

It's a pun.

The rhetoric site *Silva Rhetoricae* hosted by BYU and maintained by Dr. Gideon Burton provides the following definition of pun under *[paranomasia](http://rhetoric.byu.edu/Figures/P/paronomasia.htm)*:

> Using words that sound alike but that differ in meaning (punning).

In your example, let's break down the words at play:

- *avocado*, a tree well-known for its edible fruit
- *cardio*, heart-related activity
- *avocardio*, the nonce portmanteau from combining *avocado* and *cardio*

In this case, the *-cado* in *avocado* is echoed in the *-cardio* in *avocardio*, which has similar sounds. *Avocado* and *avocardio* sound alike. But they have two meanings. Literally the avocado is a fruit, but *avocardio* plays off of the avocado's perceived status as a heart-healthy food (e.g. "[An avocado a day keeps the cardiologist away](https://news.psu.edu/story/339842/2015/01/07/research/avocado-day-keeps-cardiologist-away)," Penn State) to create a new word and meaning. That fits the definition of *paronomasia*.

Now, whether it's a good pun or one where its forced similarity is groan-worthy depends on your aesthetic judgment and your taste in t-shirts.